# Issue running project under Spring + Maven configurations

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Hi everybody I was working with Spring MVC 3.0.1 and Maven to build up a simple project but I had this error and I've been dealing with some issues and still haven't found the solution. Hope anyone can help. The error is the following:

```
Feb 19, 2016 9:37:09 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanExpressionResolver
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionResolver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1858)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
    ... 17 more

Feb 19, 2016 9:37:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanExpressionResolver
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionResolver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1858)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
    ... 17 more
```

Here is also my pom.xml file and web.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.controller</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>TestRH</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
        <name>EBR Spring Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>EBR External Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
   <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
        <generatePackage>weather.wsdl</generatePackage>
        <schemas>
            <schema>
                <url>http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL</url>
            </schema>
        </schemas>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

to this :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-M1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this when running build install: Failure to find org.springframework.ws:spring-ws:jar:2.0.0-M1 in http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release was cached in the local repository

Answer (score 0):

try:

Replace version dependency spring-ws

you use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

replace to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0-M1</version>
</dependency>
```

Better still would be up to the latest version
**2.1.4.RELEASE**

Comment: Now I'm getting this when running build install: Failure to find org.springframework.ws:spring-ws:jar:2.0.0-M1 in repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release was cached in the local repository –

Comment: you are getting this error because, as is a milestone version in the repository spring release it should not be. try change libs milestone to **2.1.4.RELEASE** (_spring-ws_ and _spring-ws-core_)

Comment: Well I already change it to the the one you posted **2.1.4.RELEASE** but still giving me the same error.